# Align inputs next to labels in article section

Tags: html, css

I know that a lot of questions related to this topic have been asked. I went through most of them, but I still cannot figure out why it does not work in my case.

My website is divided into two parts using the aside and article tags. I would like my form to be inside the article tag. Moreover, I would like my labels to be aligned next to my inputs. I tried:

```
label{ display: inline-block; width: XXpx; text-align: right;} 

label{ display: block; width: XXpx; float: left;}
```

and other configurations, but it does not work. The fact is I use display: table-cell in the aside and article tags to get the background color to extend all the way down the page. I am wondering if it has an impact.

HTML

```
<section>
.
.
.
<article>
.
.
.
<form method="post" action="Y.php">
<label for="name" id="name1"> Name<em>*</em> </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name2" placeholder="Ex : Tom" autofocus="" required="" /> <br>
<label for="email"> Email<em>*</em>  </label>  
<input type="email" name="email" id="email1" placeholder="Ex : Tom@gmail.com" required="" /> <br>  
</form>
</article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
aside, article{ display: table-cell;  vertical-align: top; text-align: justify; line-height: 1.5em;}
label{ display: inline-block; width: XXpx; text-align: right;}
```

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the labels to have the same width, so that all elements line up nicely?
You can do that by adding a `min-width` to your labels:

```
label {
  min-width: 100px; /* Or whatever value and unit you want. */
}
```

Live example with your code: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/GggQRR